# Does Gravity Warp Coulomb's force?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, relativity

Does gravity effect the "sphericalness" of the Coulomb force?

For example, is the field 1 meter above a charge weaker than the field 1 meter below the charge?

Could a 0.014% difference in the field be detected?

Have there been any such experiments run?

**Edit:**

In answer to firtree's question below, I am working on the admittedly heretical idea that the "curvature of space" is actually the flow of space into a massive body and as such space is flowing into Earth at 11km/s at its surface (its escape velocity).

At the moment, I'm trying to develop a model for length contraction.  Using the notions of perturbation theory and $r=ct$ one could perhaps reformulate Coulomb's Law:
$$F(r)=\frac{q_1q_2}{\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{4\pi r^2}$$
as:
$$F(t)=\frac{q_1q_2}{\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{4\pi c^2t^2}$$
Time moving against the flow:
$$t_u=\frac{d}{c-v}$$
and with the flow:
$$t_d=\frac{d}{c+v}$$
The 0.014% comes from comparing the force for the two times plugging in $d=1$ and $v\approx11,000$ m/s

However, as the calculation of length contraction illustrates, the actual effect is dependent on the two way speed of light.  And aside from that, if things actually worked this way it would seem to violate Newton's 3rd law.  But, I just wanted to get a sanity check and see if there were any experimental (or theoretical) results related to this.

Comment: For clarification, are you looking for a super-precise answer involving general relativity, or are you just looking for an answer that assumes that Newtonian gravity is accurate enough?

Comment: @RedAct I *believe* that if this were the case, it would violate Newton's 3rd law.  I'm basically just looking for a sanity check to see if 1: such an effect would be detectable and 2: if such an attempt was made to detect it and 3: that such attempts always returned  a null result. -- Also, I'm not looking for a super precise answer, but definitely I'm thinking in the context of GR.

Comment: In GR it surely does. But where does the figure 0.014% come from? GR effect is orders of magnitude smaller.

Comment: @firtree I edited the details into the question.

Comment: I know of no such experiments, and I think 0.014% difference would be noticed very early, perhaps in 19th century. The precision of experimental check of Maxwell's equations is much higher. And this heretical idea (in no way new) is cut off by many other checks, much earlier than discussing Coulomb force. Are you familiar with GR? If so, Maxwell-Einstein equations in static grav field are the same as $\varepsilon/\varepsilon_0=\mu/\mu_0=1/\sqrt{g_{00}}$ where $g_{00}\approx 1+2\phi/c^2$, $\phi$ being Newtonian grav potential and $\phi/c^2\sim 10^{-9}$ near Earth.

Comment: Reference: Landau and Lifshitz _The Classical Theory of Fields_, the problem after §90 and the §99.

Comment: @firtree I'll try to get my hands on a copy of L&L.  "..is cut off by many other checks" - Any guidance you may have here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you assume some non-relativistic medium, then it is essentially the [Le Sage's theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Sage's_theory_of_gravitation) with many problems. If you assume relativistic framework, then it is some kind of _vector field theory_, and it is shown in 1919 that the gravitation is a _tensor_ field interaction (see Misner, Thorne, Wheeler; Feynman, Morinigo, Wagner). Vector and tensor theories look somewhat similar only on the non-relativistic level. And L&L essentialy says what I quoted, not much more, it is just other textbooks don't discuss static grav field problem.

Comment: @firtree I don't think my thinking is related to Le Sage.  I found L&L online; I'll go through it.  Thanks for your hint; I'll try to track down the Vector / Tensor issue.

Answer (score -1):

Yes gravity affects voltages and forces in circuits but has very small effect

suppose you have vertical wire on globe directly which is 1 meter ,electron mass is 10 power -31 kg,and you know globe mass and radius , by simple calculations depending newton's law of gravity and work's law you get:

the voltage gravity  applied on wire is 10 power -26

and it is nothing!